# I have written this function to get the size of a string, can it be optimized?

Tags: python, string, optimization, size

I don't want to use python functions to calculate but I want to implement a function myself. The problem comes when the chain is very long. The program starts to take about 5 minutes.

[image]

Comment: I don't think using recursion is a good idea here.

Comment: I've no idea why you'd want to do this... but why not just set `length = 0`... then loop over the string... `for ch in str: length += 1` and then `return length` - I'd also call your string `text` or something so you're not shadowing the `str` builtin... as @Danil says... there's absolutely no need for recursion here... (and also - I haven't tested it but it doesn't look like it'd even work anyway)

Comment: Also, strings are immutable in python. When you take slice from a string python makes a copy of your string. You can even profile your program to see what part takes too long. Also, recursion isn't very deep in python, so your function can count up to about 1000 or so elements string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use `len()`?
I think what you're trying to do is just `len('holaaaaaa')` and I don't think that it can be more optimized than that.
if you want to implement the function your self then you cand do:

```
def StringLenght(string):
    return len(string)
```